# python isalpha doesn't handle unicode combing marks properly?

Tags: python, unicode, combining-marks

I encountered weird ukrainian word **Кири́лл**. I converted it to unicode and tested it with isalpha, which returned False. I looked around and found that this word contains character named 'combining acute accent'. So the letter **и́** is actually a combination of two characters: **и** and **́**. If I understood it correctly, combining marks (like this acute accent) are intended only to modify other characters. So isalpha should recognize this string as a word. Am I wrong? Is there any way to get correct results?
The word in question in utf8:

> > > word = '\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xcc\x81\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbb'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to replace the strings of any modifier characters since a modifier character is not considered alpha

```
modifiers = "\xcc\x81|<OTHER>|<MODIFIERS>"

text_to_analyze = re.sub(modifiers,"",my_text)
print unicode(text_to_analyze,"utf8").isalpha()
```