# Check whether a string is alphabetical for languages other than english

Tags: python, text, unicode, nlp

I am working with text data with a mix of several languages. Now trying to test whether a token/string is alphabetical, which means is potentially a word. 
Is there some built in function like `'somestring'.isAlpha()` to test whether a string is alphabetical for other languages (Portuguese and Spanish)? I tried `'ó'.isalpha()`, which returns `False`.

What I thought of now is to get the Unicode table. Find the starting and ending letter and test whether a letter is in the range of alphabets.

Comment: Aside: if you're working with unicode data, you should really be working in Python 3.  It's much saner.

Comment: `'ó'.decode("utf-8").isalpha()`, that will fail too though for certain input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this solve your problem?

```
>>> u'é'.isalpha()
True
```

Just as an FYI, the below example works perfectly in Python 3:

```
words = ['você', 'quer', 'uma', 'maçã']
for word in words:
    word.isalpha()
```

In python 2, you could do something like:

```
for word in words:
    unicode(word, "utf-8").isalpha()
```

Comment: `word.isalpha()` by itself won't show the user any output, though.. maybe `print(word.isalpha())`?

Comment: It will in the terminal, but yes, maybe.

Comment: Your Python 2 example doesn't work for me. It prints and encodes "Кири́лл" correctly, and `u"Кири́лл".isalpha()` returns `True`, but it wont work with `unicode(code, "utf-8").isalpha()`.

Comment: For some reason, both python2 and python3 think "и́" is not alpha.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920882/python-isalpha-doesnt-handle-unicode-combing-marks-properly

Answer (score 0):

This library is not from NLTK either but certainly helps.

1) Install langdetect Library
$ pip install langdetect

**Supported Python versions 2.6, 2.7, 3.x.**

2) Test your code

```
>>> from langdetect import detect

>>> detect("War doesn't show who's right, just who's left.")
'en'
>>> detect("Ein, zwei, drei, vier")
'de'
```

Reference Link :

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langdetect?